# Tomcat won't recognize a second application when it's added

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am creating Web Applications using Eclipse and Tomcat v6.0

I have one dynamic web application running on the server and it's working fine.  However if I add a second web application it will not be recognized by Tomcat.

Everything appears to be fine and there are no errors, but i cannot load the application when i put in the correct url.

Could anybody tell me why this might be happening, or what files or settings i could change to fix it.

Comment: To avoid the obvious: did you restart Tomcat after adding?

Comment: the servers plugin has a number of settings - what are yours.

Comment: I'd guess that your URL or deployment is wrong before I'd assume that Tomcat is bugged.  Tomcat can certainly handle more than one deployed WAR at a time.

Comment: Tried restarting multiple times, and was able to get either application running on it's own.

Which settings do you want me to detail Bozho?

Comment: I've never seen this before. Aren't they both using the same context name? Is there anything in Tomcat startup/deploy logs? Does it work if you detach Eclipse from the whole story (thus manual deploy on Tomcat)?